# How can I use the pipe (|) symbol in a table?

Tags: support, markdown, tables

I must use the pipe (`|`) symbol in a table cell. How can I do that? Is there an escape character for it?

For example:

```
|Code |Comment   |
|-----|----------|
|a | b|Comment 1 |
```

Table:

| Code | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| a | b |

But I want:

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Escape it with a backslash? That works for many things in Markdown. Alternatively, use one of the HTML entities for the pipe character, e.g. `&#124;` (or the more meaningful `&vert;` as mentioned by @GalaxyCat105).

The following Markdown:

```
|foo|bar   |
|---|------|
|\| |&#124;|
```

produces this:

| foo | bar |
| --- | --- |
| | | | |

Answer (score 7):

As the other answers have mentioned, you could escape it with a backslash, which is probably a better solution than mine, but you could also use the HTML entities `&vert;` or `&#x7C;` in place of the pipe character.

```
|Code  |Comment    |
|------|-----------|
|a &vert; b | Comment 1 |
```

| Code | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| a | b | Comment 1 |

Answer (score 4):

The escape character you're looking for is a backslash:

```
|Code     |Comment    |
|---------|-----------|
| a \| b  | Comment 1 |
```

This gives:

| Code | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| a | b | Comment 1 |